# Getting "Index of /" when trying to visit my website – How to open webpage uploaded to FTP in web browser

Tags: ftp

I uploaded my website using FileZilla to the remote site folder that is simply called "/". When I right-click the folder to get the URL and enter the URL into the browser, all I get is "Index of /" with a list of files and folders. I'm missing a step no doubt. I've searched on the internet to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

FileZilla *"Copy URL(s) to clipboard"* command puts **FTP** URL to the clipboard (note the leading `ftp://`). If you paste this into a web browser, it will make the browser behave as **FTP** client. So it will show you the same, what FileZilla does (both being FTP clients). *(as of 2021, web browsers are removing support for FTP, so this won't work anymore anyway)*

You need to use **HTTP** URL in the web browser to see your web page. FileZilla cannot show you the HTTP URL. You need to type it on your own. Some other FTP clients do though. For example *my* WinSCP has [Generate HTTP URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url#options) function.

If you do not know your web page HTTP URL, you should contact your hosting provider.
See also my answer to [How to get HTTP URL of file uploaded to FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46417961/850848#46419531).